# Create a custom NOP commerce task

Tags: nopcommerce

I'm trying to understand the following code used in Nop Commerece task. It has classes which are implemented as below. The project is in the `Plugins` folder. One class implements `ITask` interface.

```
Public class foo:ITask
{
  public void Execute()
  {
    ......

  } 
 }
```

Another implements `BasePlugin, Iplugin`

```
 public class SmartWarehousePlugin : BasePlugin, IPlugin
 {

   public override void Install()
  {
    ...
  }

  public override void Uninstall()
  {
    ....
  }
   ....
 }
```

I understand the concept of Task and Plugin in NOP. I went through different tutorials. But I didn't find one where `ITask` and `BasePlugin,IPlugin` are used together. Why and when we need to do this?

Comment: This question is bit unclear to me, what you want to know? How to create a custom task?

Comment: See the last 2 lines of question. Why `ITask` and `BasePlugin,IPlugin` are used together. Why and when we need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, `ITask` is an interface, using that you can create your own task in task scheduler and `BasePlugin` interface having install, uninstall methods , so using that methods, you can add custom things at installation/uninstallation.

Now the question are When? and Why? So, when you want to create/start your task just after plugin installation *(or for similar kind of functionality)* at that time you can use both together. *Why part* depends on your requirements.